# Device.StartTimer equivalent in Native Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm working on an application that simulates an old phone keypad like the ones in a Nokia 3310 where multiple button clicks changes the letter thats being written from 1 to A, B, etc.

I've originally built the application in Xamarin Forms but the assignment needs it to be in Native Xamarin so I need to pass it there. The original code I used in Xamarin forms was the following:

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
            if (ButtonCount < 1)
            {
                TimeSpan tt = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
                Device.StartTimer(tt, NumberofClicks);
            }
            ButtonCount++;
        }
```

With the NumberofClicks method being the following:

```
bool NumberofClicks()

        {
            if (ButtonCount > 1)
            {
                 //Event for 2 button clicks
            }
            else
            {
               //Event for 1 button click
            }
            ButtonCount = 0;
            return false;
```

Since Xamarin Native supports applying tags to buttons I want to try and make a method for all the buttons to be more efficient where it uses the tag it has, for this purpose I use the expression of var Btn = ((Android.Widget.Button)btnPresionado) so I can simply use Btn.Tag.ToString() when adding it to text. As for what I tried to use as a Device.StarTimer equivalent, I used a System.Threading.Timer as seen in the following code:

```
public void ButtonClick(object btnPresionado, EventArgs e)
        {  
            if (ButtonCount < 1)
            {
                System.Threading.Timer timer = new Timer(NumberofClicks,btnPresionado, 2000, Infinite);
            } 
            ButtonCount++;
        }

        public void NumberofClicks(object btnPresionado)
        {
            var Btn = ((Android.Widget.Button)btnPresionado);
            if (ButtonCount > 1)
            {
                //Double click event
            }
            else
            {
                //Single click event
            }
            ButtonCount = 0;
        }
```

Unfortunately when testing this, it does not work and makes the app crash in the emulator (I cant see what exactly goes wrong since this is a 3rd party emulator because Hyper-V simply refuses to install itself on my PC at the moment) so I want to ask what would be a good equivalent for Device.StartTimer() or what exactly am I doing wrong here?

Thank you

Comment: what is the exception that causes the crash?  Add some exception handling to your code to help you figure it out.